# Advice Tuning my server

Tags: linux, mysql, performance-tuning

as many others I Learn many info from you in the past and now I manage to run server independently , now I am new to sql tuning and I been searching around the web a while now and tuning seems to be a difficult think so I would appreciate some advice/help . Can anyone comment on the results below are good, bad or worst.

I downloaded and launched the mysqltuner.pl and the result is :

```
    -------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1d 5h 10m 1s (488K q [4.654 qps], 9K conn, TX: 2B, RX: 114M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 85% / 15%
[--] Total buffers: 522.0M global + 1.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 691.9M (8% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (1/488K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 5% (9/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/729.0K
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (465K cached / 30 reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 70.9% (305K cached / 431K selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 38311
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 35K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 1369
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 58% (6K on disk / 11K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (9 created / 9K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 33% (2K open / 5K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 3% (160/5K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (222K immediate / 222K locks)

-------- InnoDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB BufferPool Size :450.0M
[--] InnoDB BufferPool Inst :1
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 450.0M/310.3M
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 16M)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    tmp_table_size (> 32M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 32M)
```

my.cnf as follow

```
mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size= 16777216
query_cache_limit=1048576

innodb_buffer_pool_instances =1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 450M

tmp_table_size      = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
join_buffer_size=256K

skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=TRUE

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

and below the server information and memory

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 6
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.9.1
stepping        : 3
cpu MHz         : 2000.074
cache size      : 32 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 4
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good unfair_spinlock pni hypervisor
bogomips        : 4000.14
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 6
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.9.1
stepping        : 3
cpu MHz         : 2000.074
cache size      : 32 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 4
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good unfair_spinlock pni hypervisor
bogomips        : 4000.14
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 6
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.9.1
stepping        : 3
cpu MHz         : 2000.074
cache size      : 32 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 4
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good unfair_spinlock pni hypervisor
bogomips        : 4000.14
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 6
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.9.1
stepping        : 3
cpu MHz         : 2000.074
cache size      : 32 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 4
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good unfair_spinlock pni hypervisor
bogomips        : 4000.14
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 4
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 6
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.9.1
stepping        : 3
cpu MHz         : 2000.074
cache size      : 32 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 4
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good unfair_spinlock pni hypervisor
bogomips        : 4000.14
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 5
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 6
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.9.1
stepping        : 3
cpu MHz         : 2000.074
cache size      : 32 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 4
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good unfair_spinlock pni hypervisor
bogomips        : 4000.14
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

and memory as follow :

```
 free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8060476    7057992    1002484          0     305180    4631680
-/+ buffers/cache:    2121132    5939344
Swap:      1048568     383800     664768

show variables like '%query_cache%';
+------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                | Value    |
+------------------------------+----------+
| have_query_cache             | YES      |
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576  |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096     |
| query_cache_size             | 16777216 |
| query_cache_type             | ON       |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF      |
+------------------------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 SHOW STATUS LIKE 'qcache%';
+-------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name           | Value   |
+-------------------------+---------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 1597    |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 4456848 |
| Qcache_hits             | 313793  |
| Qcache_inserts          | 120859  |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 48666   |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 6298    |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 3869    |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 10227   |
+-------------------------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am using Mysql 5.6.12
Thanks in advance for your help
STef

Percona conf

```
# Generated by Percona Configuration Wizard (http://tools.percona.com/) version REL5-20120208
# Configuration name server-8 generated for mail.com at 2015-07-09 23:48:22

[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
skip-name-resolve
sql-mode                       = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
sysdate-is-now                 = 1
innodb                         = FORCE
innodb-strict-mode             = 1

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 10240

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 256M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 6G

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

Comment: The first rule of MySQL tuning: Don't do it, except you have an actual problem you need to fix. The defaults are quite sane and you should fiddle around with them only if your specific use case makes them work bad. If you have a problem, please explain it in your question.

Comment: Hi Sven , thx for your reply  I don`t have any particular problem  I was trying just to tune a bit mysql , but   you probably right  I will leave a s it is  and when the problem comes I will sort it out

Comment: I don't agree the defaults are sane. On top of my head, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is too small unless you run sakila-size database. Missing `skip-name-resolve` can bite. I like Percona's config generator http://tools.percona.com/wizard . It gives more or less good config which can be tuned in case you need to.

Comment: There are problems here with your application's database queries, so you should fix the application also.

Comment: so what is your suggestion base on the outcome  above ? I reset my.cnf to default but searching googling around they all suggest to have a good tuned server configuration , Above I update the post with percona wizard conf :
should I stick with that one ? 
Thx